# Xamarin.Forms Android app http/s API call to .Net core 2.1

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, httpclient, asp.net-core-2.1, self-signed

I'm having troubles with connecting Xamarin.Android to .net core api because od self signed certificates.

I'm working with xamarin.forms .net standard project targeting UWP and Android at the moment, and .net core 2.1 rest for backend services.

Targeted Android is min 5.0 max 9.1. Working around this realy long so couldn't find any solution anywhere. Calling API is working from UWP but android is dead totaly.

Greetings, Sadam

Comment: What is your actual question? I see a series of vaguely related statements.

Comment: Can you paste the some code or what you are getting exception?

Comment: This is exception
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+d__64.MoveNext () [0x00478] in <25ebe1083eaf4329b5adfdd5bbb7aa57>:0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+d__49.MoveNext () [0x000ca] in <25ebe1083eaf4329b5adfdd5bbb7aa57>:0

It is problem up to mono bug i think, it is not up to ssl self signed certificate...

Answer (score 0):

after working around this morning I got this exception... I think it's not SSL the problem, it's some bug in mono

at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+d__64.MoveNext () [0x00478] in <25ebe1083eaf4329b5adfdd5bbb7aa57>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+d__49.MoveNext () [0x000ca] in <25ebe1083eaf4329b5adfdd5bbb7aa57>:0

Greetings,
Sadam